# Take screenshot of subscriber in opentok Android

Tags: java, android, screenshot, opentok, tokbox

I want to take **screen shot of subscriber frame in opentok Android**. I am able to take screen shot of other xml components but not able to take screenshot of the opentok subscriber.

Can anyone help me for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If "subscriber frame" refers to video, they may be using `SurfaceView`, which does not work with a lot of "screenshot" approaches. You could try using the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+, or you could see what ways there are for getting your chosen screenshot code to work with `SurfaceView`.

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer but couldn't found anything. Please let me know if you found any workaround for that taking screenshot of vonage videocall programmatically in android. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to take a screenshot of the subscriber video, you could have a look at this [sample repository](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/main/Live-Photo-Capture), You just need to add ScreenshotVideoRenderer to your subscriber object and call ((ScreenshotVideoRenderer) subscriber.getRenderer()).saveScreenshot() to get the subscribers screenshot which is stored in phone storage. Let me know in case you need any further assistance required from my side.

Thanks